# getCause() function of Throwable class (in Java) is not working as expected

Tags: java, exception, null, throwable

I am getting null while calling the `getCause` function of `Throwable`.

```
package com.salman.demo;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            NormalClass.testIt();
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            System.out.println(th.getCause());
        }
    }
}


package com.salman.demo;

import com.salman.exceptions.ValidationException;

public class NormalClass {
    public static void testIt() throws ValidationException {
        System.out.println("Inside testIt funtion.");

        throw new ValidationException("Validation Exception..");
    }
}
```

On running `MyClass`, it prints following output

```
Inside testIt funtion.
null
```

however on debugging this, I can see value of cause private variable is set to `ValidationException` which is expected but while calling getter of that private field returns null.

Answer (score 3):

The `ValidationException` you've thrown will be `th` in your calling code... there's no cause *for* that `ValidationException`. The point of `getCause()` is for one exception to be able to refer to another one as an underlying cause - but there's only one exception in your case.

The fact that you see the private `cause` variable's value being the `ValidationException` is entirely in line with how that field is documented (emphasis mine):

> The throwable that caused this throwable to get thrown, or null if
>   throwable was not caused by another throwable, or if the causative
>   throwable is unknown. **If this field is equal to this throwable itself,
>   it indicates that the cause of this throwable has not yet been
>   initialized.**

And that's why `getCause()` is implemented as:

```
return (cause==this ? null : cause);
```

If you want to see the intended chaining in effect, you could create two exceptions, one chained to the other:

```
throw new ValidationException("Validation Exception..",
    new IllegalArgumentException("Bang!"));
```

Now calling `getCause()` on the `ValidationException` will return the `IllegalArgumentException`.

You probably just want to change your calling code to log `th` instead of `th.getCause()` though.

Comment: Thanks Jon for your valuable input. I was not aware of that behavior of throwing exception. Actually I was generating some metrics based on type of exception. I found another way for getting Exception name th.getClass().getSimpleName() , gives the actual cause of the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Your exception is the first one in the chain, so it does not have a cause.

If you want to test, it you need to have chain of exception, so you thorw one catch it and throw new one which is constructed using the previous.

Comment: Thanks Zielu for your input.